# Possible to create element and bind to VM after .applyBindings()?

Tags: knockout.js

Sometimes a JS library modifies HTML elements or creates new ones. In my case the JQuery Texteditor, a slim WYSIWYG editor, requires a textarea element to get started (by calling .jqte() on the element). The editor will then alter the existing html, the textarea will actually disappear and the text will be contained in a div instead.

Therefore a value binding on the textarea will not sync with the model. To make the editor work, I need to create a bound element after the text editor has done its modifications.

A way to start the editor with the required html pre-set would be a solution, but the editor does not offer such initialization.

I believe that knockout will only bind to the elements that were initial bound by .applyBindings(). Or is it somehow possible to bind to a newly created element? Could I, for example, initially create a value binding for an input element and later "redirect" it to the text editor's field?

Comment: Look at the computedObservables. If I understood you well it should do the trick.

Comment: The point is not to bind to something else than an observable, the point is to bind a dynamically created html element to the VM (the property to bind to in the VM already exists).

Comment: Create custom binding, bind it against a empty element, create a new element, do the stuff you want and then append that element to the element boudn to your custom binding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of APIs that might be helpful to you:

`ko.applyBindingAccessorsToNode` and `ko.applyBindingsToNode` can directly add bindings to an element.

- `ko.applyBindingAccessorsToNode` was added in 3.0 and takes in accessor functions that return the value to bind against to ensure that dependencies are isolated between bindings.

You would call it like:

```
ko.applyBindingAccessorsToNode(element, { 
    text: function() { 
         return context.$data.first() + ' ' + context.$data.last();
    }
}, context);
```

- `ko.applyBindingsToNode` will wrap the values in accessor functions for you, but you would want to make sure that you are not accessing dependencies in the object that you pass (don't access observable values when building the bindings that you pass like  `text: first() + ' ' + last()`

A typical call would look like:

```
ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { text: myValue, visible: showValue }, context);
```

Another call that can be useful is `ko.applyBindingsToDescendants`. You call it like:

```
ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(viewModelOrContext, element);
```

This would force binding the children of an element using the normal binding mechanism. If you really have a situation where the markup comes in later and has `data-bind` bindings on them, then you could call this on the parent of the new elements. You would really only want to call this once though, unless the child elements are being dynamically swapped by whatever library you are dealing with.

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot. With this I can use the editor with knockout, example fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/timvdh/P4xpx/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a binding handler thats add your element to a bound element, like

http://jsfiddle.net/G68Ct/

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myBinding = {
    init: function(element) {
        var myElement = document.createElement("span");
        myElement.innerText = "My element";
        element.appendChild(myElement);
    }
};
```